# About using Solidity optimization

Tags: solidity, compilation, optimization

It is a well known fact that in optimizing mode compilers usually have more bugs than in non-optimizing mode.

As such, do you recommend to use the Solidity compiler with or without optimization? My contract is not particularly computationally expensive.

Also, Ethereum Wallet does not have "optimization" checkbox. Does it call the compiler in optimizing or non-optimizing mode?